Python: Need help on the class method
I have a class "Duck" and "Dog" as shown:
class Duck:

    def quack(self):
        print("quack")

class Dog:

    def bark(self):
        print("I just bark")

Defined another class as shown in two ways and initiated:
case:1
class ItQuacks:

    def __init__(self, animal):
        **animal.quack()**

If I initiate it as ItQuacks(Duck), it is not printing anything. I am expecting "quack" to be printed. Whereas ItQuacks(Duck()) prints "quack".
case:2
class ItQuacks:

    def __init__(self, animal):
        **animal.quack(self)**

But if I initiate it as ItQuacks(Duck), it is printing "quack" as expected
May I know if Duck() has self by default. Can someone explain this concept.

Try type(Duck) and type(Duck())... first is a type which has no self concept, second is an actual object of that type, thus has a self concept.

Also you probably are confused with what self actually is in your code... try adding print("quack id:", id(self)) and print("ItQuacks id:", id(self)) is each function.

Note that when you use animal.quack(self) the self in question is an ItQuacks object, not the Duck object or class. This is evidently going to lead to an error because you are passing two arguments to the quack method. One is the implicit self (and which belongs to the class Duck), that is always passed, no matter what. The other is the self that you have passed which belongs to the class ItQuacks.

You might be looking for the @classmethod decorator for some of these use cases? Or perhaps you could convert these into static methods instead.

You should be seeing an error message in the cases where it doesn’t work, not just nothing…‽
